# Printing whole lines that fulfill specific condition into a different files

Tags: perl

I am trying to count the number of how many times same element repeats in an array and if it repeats more time then I want to print whole lines into a different files.

My input:

```
ATM 4387 FE   HEM A 142       
ATM 4388  CHA HEM A 142      
ATM 4389  CHB HEM A 142      
ATM 4431  CHA HEM B 147     
ATM 4432  CHB HEM B 147     
ATM 4433  CHC HEM B 147     
ATM 4434  CHD HEM B 147     
ATM 4559  O   HOH A 156     
ATM 4560  O   HOH A 159
```

So I am putting elements `[3]`, `[4]` and `[5]` into a seperate arrays, counting the number of its appearance and setting up conditions that if it appears `>1` then printing them into a seperate files. Another part of the script is matching elemets from array `@lig` (`ligands.txt file`) and elements from `@ligands_pdb` array. and if it appears to match then then element from `@ligands_pdb` should also be included into a filename.

My `@lig` array looks like this:

```
HEC
HEM
HEP
IGP
IPM
LLP
```

So since `HEM` is matching then this should also be included into a filename.
Current error I am getting is `Use of uninitialized value $ligands_pdb in concatenation (.) or string at example.pl line 58, <$_[...]> line 5436.`

```
  #! usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use 5.010;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data;
my $ligands_pdb;
my @ligands_pdb;

my $ligand_file = 'ligands.txt';
open (LIG, $ligand_file)or die "Cannot open $ligand_file, $!";
my @lig= <LIG>;
close LIG;
#print "@lig\n";
my $flag = 0;
for my $pdb ( glob '*pdb' ) 
{
    #printf "# %s\n", $pdb;
    open my $fh, "<", $pdb;
    for my $line ( <$fh> ) 
{
        chomp( $line );
    if ( $line =~ m/^ATM / ) 
    {
        my @cols = split ' ', $line;
        #print @cols;
        #print "$cols[3]\n";
        push @ligands_pdb, $cols[3];
        my ($chain_id, $res_no) = ( $cols[4], $cols[5] );
            defined $res_no
            or die "Unable to grok line: $line";
            push @{ $data->{$chain_id}->{$res_no} }, $line;
     }

    foreach (@ligands_pdb)
    {
        if ("@lig" =~/$_/ )
        {
            $flag = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $flag = 1;
        }
     for my $chain_id ( keys %$data ) 
    {
        for my $res_no ( keys %{ $data->{$chain_id} } ) 
        {
        #print "$chain_id\n";
        #print "$res_no\n";
        my @lines = @{ $data->{$chain_id}->{$res_no} };
                if ( $flag ==0 and scalar @lines > 1 ) 
        {
                    open my $out, ">> $ligands_pdb . '#' . $chain_id . '#' . $res_no . '.txt';";    #line 58
                    print $out $_ for (@lines);
                    close $out;
        }
        @ligands_pdb = ();
        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

I am expecting to have created 2 files and that content of them is:

```
HEM#A#142:

ATM 4387 FE   HEM A 142       
ATM 4388  CHA HEM A 142      
ATM 4389  CHB HEM A 142

HEM#B#147:

ATM 4431  CHA HEM B 147     
ATM 4432  CHB HEM B 147     
ATM 4433  CHC HEM B 147     
ATM 4434  CHD HEM B 147
```

Comment: So, your code does not compile...I suspect it is a snippet of a larger file.  Anyway, you need to declare `my @chain_id` and `my @res_id` somewhere, and change `my $counts = ()` to `my %counts = ()`.

Comment: You should edit (and test) that the code you provide to SO can at least be run by copying and pasting...it makes it easier to help you.

Comment: The fix is to move a set of parens...which perl would have told you about through all of its warnings like `Use of uninitialized value $number in hash element at foo.pl line 50, <$_[...]> line 9.`  Never ignore warnings...they often mean you have overlooked something important.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I have declared all the variables and changed `%counts` and it still gives me two warnings: `Use of uninitialized value within %count1 in numeric gt (>) at ..` and `Use of uninitialized value within %count in numeric gt (>) at ..` but isnt that initialized previously? And also although it is a warning shouldnt it be able to print something or create new documents anyway?

Comment: Should the first output file A have 5 lines in it?

Comment: No, because both conditions has to be fulfilled and since in the last two lines from the example last column numbers are not the same: `156`and `159` these lines shouldnt be included.

Comment: Having variables named $count, $count1, $number, $number1 is confusing, better variable names goes a long way towards readability (and maintainability)

Comment: @xxfelixxx I agree with You but this is not direct problem why script is not printing anything. I appreciate Your answer but I would rather like to know what seems to be wrong with my script and what is direct cause of making it not working. This is just part of the script that I wrote so I think I cannot include Your answer into my script. Seems like that the problem is that some variables are not initialized although they are..

Comment: run the code through the debugger and see what everything is set to, you will see.  `perl -d foo.pl`

Comment: type 'h' for help.  's' to step through the code one line at a time.  'p $foo' to print the value of $foo.  'w $foo' to show everytime $foo changes value.

Comment: Also, your `my` variables lose their values when they go out of scope, i.e. their enclosing block `{` .. `}`, so your code isn't logically structured correctly.

Comment: For example:  `for my $foo (@bar) {  $baz = $foo; # OK } my $qux = $foo; # $foo has gone out of scope`

Comment: @xxfelixxx Yes I know but cant see which variable is out of scope when I declared everything once..all of them should be defined.. I tried to use Your script and to change mine but I get this error `Name "main::LIG" used only once: possible typo at example.pl line 27.`and nothing printed, no output..

Comment: You sure you pasted correctly? There is no LIG anywhere in the script...

Comment: @xxfelixxx Yeah I used your script and modified it or added to it my part of the script. It looks reasonable but it dont print anything, no syntax errors or anything just give me a warning that I posted in a previous comment. Do You mind if I edit the script from the question and post full code?..since only You have put some comments and answer it shouldnt make any impact on others.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I have edited it in a way of putting one more condition (matching two files) but I really dont understand how `$ligands_pdb` is uninitialized when it should be defined. I was always getting confused about this warning. Been writing this code in a while now and I really dont know how to change it anymore..

Comment: A few issues...The first is that your `@lig` probably has newlines in it, so your `$flag` might not be set correctly.  You can use the `chomp` command to get rid of them for you.  You can use a ternary operator to simplify your `if/else -> 0/1` by doing `$flag = ( $foo =~ m|bar| ) ? 1 : 0;

Comment: You have 2 variables, named `$foo` and `@foo`.  This gets very confusing quickly. ( ligands_pdb in your case )  Especially because often you will see `$foo[123]` which is referring to `@foo` not `$foo`

Comment: Instead of using `@lig` and iterating over it each time, you should just create a hash and check if that hash key is defined to set your flag.  Remembering to get rid of the newlines first.

Comment: Your $ligands_pdb is uninitialized because you never set it to anything...you probably confused it with @ligands_pdb.

Comment: Yeah I can use chomp when reading a file into an array. Oh I see why it is confusing with `@/$ligands_pdb` but if I use only one then it says that the other one is not declared..that's why I am declaring either scalar and array. Hm, I am not that experienced with using hashes, been using them few times, thats why I took this approach. I can create hash and set up the keys to be elements from `@ligands_pdb` but I am not sure how I can compare hash keys and elements from `@lig`array..

Comment: But that is what I don't understand..if I define `@ligands_pdb` why I have to define `$ligands_pdb` when it should as a scalar correspond to each element from `@ligands_pdb` and then when I declare it it says that it is uninitialized, whole thing gets me confusing :P

Comment: perl doesn't work that way, they are considered different variables entirely, that happen to have a similar name.

Comment: if you want each element of `@foo` you just do `for my $elem (@foo) { ... do something with $elem }`

Comment: To create a hash, you can just iterate over a file and set keys as you go:
`my %lig_hash; for my $line (<LIG>) { chomp($line); $lig_hash{ $line }++; }`

Comment: And then later, you can check for the existance of keys:   `$flag = defined $lig_hash{ 'some_key' } ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Notice that for a hash, `%foo`, accessing an element changes the sigil to a `$`, like `my $value = $foo{ 'some_key' }`

Comment: Similarly for arrays, `@foo`, accessing one element becomes `$foo[2]`

Comment: This is because perl was written by a Linguist, and `$` denotes a scalar, i.e. one of something, while `@` and `%` are in some sense plural.

Comment: A read of `perldoc perltrap` may be useful depending on your programming background.  https://perldoc.perl.org/perltrap.html

Comment: There is also the `perlcritic` tool you can use to get feedback and improve your code from the command line.  It will make suggestions on improving what you have.  http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Perl-Critic-1.130/lib/Perl/Critic.pm

Comment: Also, you should change the `LIG` filehandle to `$LIG` and declare it with `my`

Comment: The style of using bare filehandles has long been deprecated (and can cause bugs because they are global).

Comment: @xxfelixxx Hm I see, I changed it but it is quite since I almost never use hashes it is quite confusing by looking at the comments for me to know where exactly I should put these hashes. I understand that I can put all all elements from a file lines into a hash `lig_hash` and if I want to assess elements from specific column I just do `for my $ligands_pdb {keys %$lig_hash}` but still i get confused with hashes keys when I have to compare it with the elements from `@ion` array..and I am not sure how to put these elements in the filenames if they are matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your code using a nested hash to store the file lines, keyed off of the 2 fields.  If there are multiple lines stored, save to a new file.  I have added some debugging so you can see the flow.

**filter.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use 5.010;

use List::Util qw( uniq );

my $DEBUG = 1;
sub debug {
    my ($msg) = @_;
    print "DEBUG: $msg\n" if $DEBUG;
}

my $ligand_file = 'ligands.txt';
open( my $LIG, $ligand_file ) or die "Cannot open $ligand_file, $!";
debug("Reading ligands file: $ligand_file");
my %ligands_hash;
for my $ligand ( <$LIG> ) {
    chomp( $ligand ); # Remove trailing newline
    $ligands_hash{ $ligand } = 1;
}
close $LIG;
debug("Found ligands: " . join(',',sort keys %ligands_hash));

my %output_files;
my $flag = 0;
for my $pdb ( glob '*pdb' ) {

    my %ligands_found;
    my $data_hash_ref;

    debug("-"x40);
    debug("Working on file $pdb");
    open my $fh, "<", $pdb;
    for my $line (<$fh>) {
        chomp($line);
        if ( $line =~ m/^ATM / ) {
            $line =~ s|\s*$||;
            debug("--> Found an ATM line");
            my @cols = split ' ', $line;
            my ( $ligand, $chain_id, $res_no ) = ( $cols[3], $cols[4], $cols[5] );
            debug("--> Adding ligand $ligand to ligands_found hash");
           $ligands_found{ $ligand }++;

            defined $res_no
              or die "Unable to grok line: $line";

            # This works because perl automatically creates the missing
            # parts of nested hash (this is known as Autovivication).
            # The last part, the array is also created by the attempt
            # to push onto it, so perl assumes it should exist.
            push @{ $data_hash_ref->{$chain_id}->{$res_no} }, $line;
        }
    }

    debug("Processing ligands");
    for my $ligand (sort keys %ligands_found) {
        $flag = defined $ligands_hash{$ligand} ? 0 : 1;
        debug("--> Ligand $ligand, flag = $flag");

        for my $chain_id ( keys %$data_hash_ref ) {
            for my $res_no ( keys %{ $data_hash_ref->{$chain_id} } ) {
                debug("------> Chain Id = $chain_id, Res No = $res_no");
                my @lines = @{ $data_hash_ref->{$chain_id}->{$res_no} };
                if ( $flag == 0 and scalar @lines > 1 ) {

                    # Output filename based on first ligand with $chain_id and $res_no combo
                    my $id = join ':', $chain_id, $res_no;
                    my $outfile = $output_files{$id} ||= join( '#', $ligand, $chain_id, $res_no ) . '.txt';
                    my $nl = (scalar @lines);
                    my $nl_desc = "$nl line" . ($nl > 1 ? "s" : "");
                    debug("------> Appending $nl_desc to $outfile");
                    open my $out, ">> $outfile";
                    print $out "$_\n" for (uniq @lines);
                    close $out;

                    # Remove the lines so they don't get printed twice.
                    undef @{ $data_hash_ref->{$chain_id}->{$res_no} };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**intput.pdb**

```
ATM 4387 FE   HEM A 142       
ATM 4388  CHA HEM A 142      
ATM 4389  CHB HEM A 142      
ATM 4431  CHA HEM B 147     
ATM 4432  CHB HEM B 147     
ATM 4433  CHC IGP B 147     
ATM 4434  CHD IGP B 147     
ATM 4559  O   HOH A 156     
ATM 4560  O   HOH A 159
```

**HEM#A#142.txt**

```
ATM 4387 FE   HEM A 142
ATM 4388  CHA HEM A 142
ATM 4389  CHB HEM A 142
```

**HEM#B#147.txt**

```
ATM 4431  CHA HEM B 147
ATM 4432  CHB HEM B 147
ATM 4433  CHC IGP B 147
ATM 4434  CHD IGP B 147
```

Comment: I tried updated version it is working well apart from one thing. I have ran it ot the larger dataset and for instance if under `4th column` where `HEM` is matched, `HEM (the one that is follwed by B)` there is some other molecule that is matched `IGP (for example)`. What happens is that script first searches for 1st condition and it finds first `HEM and IGP` and it automatically generates 4 files `(HEM#A#142, HEM#B#147, IGP#A#142,IGP#B#147)` instead of two `(HEM#A#142, IGP#B#147)`. So, each file should be unique and values of last two col shouldnr repeate

Comment: I am really sorry because the data is so diverse and I have gave bad example with `HEM`. If it does not requires very big changes in the script I would really appreciate your help. Sorry once again.

Comment: So what would go into IGG#B#142 would go into HEM#A#142 if that file exists already?  i.e. first file with B#142 combo gets all further B#142 lines?

Comment: By the way...your deeply nested code inspired me to write a perl package:  `Devel::Scope` which has a `debug` method that you can adjust its verbosity by indent (scope) levels.

Comment: You can try it out by running: `sudo cpan Devel::Scope`

Comment: It is running now without errors, I will go trough script to see do I understand all of it..but have to check it because from output that u updated `IGP#B#147` should be another file and it should have content of `ATM 4433  CHC IGP B 147
ATM 4434  CHD IGP B 147`

Comment: ok, but you are contradicting your earlier statements that they should all go into the HEM file...anyway, you have enough to work with to make it do what you want.

Comment: Just look at the comment where I wrote yesterday that file `IGP#B#147.txt` should also be generated, which actually makes a problem for me

Comment: I went trough the script and most of it I understand well clearly.. it just has to be opposite that file creates whenever it differsin `4th column` but I dont know how to change it cus im bad with this style..You have already helped me alot and I appreciate it, but I cannot use this code then.. in the previous few comments from yesterday u can see that I have mention how to change it and which files should be created..

Comment: github.com/srdjanma/sergio